# Jquery quicksand callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback, quicksand

I am trying to return the number of elements after the quicksand has arranged them

http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

this should kinda work

```
function adjust_height (){
                 var getall = $('#wrapper .li').length;
                 console.log(getall);
}
        $(".portfolio-content").quicksand($filteredData, {
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            adjustHeight:false

        },function (){
                  adjust_height ();

               });
```

but I am getting the previous set length , example , if there is 4 , and on click I have 2 ,the count is 4 , on next click  count is 2 . seems like I am late with my count

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/EVagr/1/

Everything working as expected.

Try to update quicksand and jquery js files.

Comment: thnx I placed it on the wrong place, had 2 quicksands runing , fixed here  http://jsfiddle.net/gbu8Y/15/

Answer (score 1):

In your **Quicksand Callback function**, under `adjust_height();` add this:

```
var filteredSize = $filteredData.size();

alert(filteredSize);

// If the above var doesn't work, try this variant.
// var filteredSize = $($filteredData).size();
```